# Non-exported activities: launched on emulators; SecurityException on phones

Tags: android, android-activity, android-emulator, adb, root

I have a **non-exported activity** in my project.

If I try to launch it on my phone using `adb`:

```
adb shell am start -n "packagename/activityname"
```

I get the error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException:
Permission Denial: starting Intent { ... } from null (...) not exported from uid ...
```

But, if I run the same command on an emulator, then everything works Okay. How comes?

Comment: The user account that `adb shell` run as has greater rights on an emulator, AFAIK.

Answer (score 5):

> But, if I run the same command on an emulator, then everything works Okay. How comes?

An emulator instance runs as root by default, meaning that more system processes has root rights compared to a non-rooted device.

Consider the `ps` command output `grep`-ed with `adbd` and `sh` (i.e. `adb shell ps | grep 'adbd'` and `adb shell ps | grep 'sh'`, respectively). You might see the following (with different `PID` and `PPID` on your device/emulator, of course):

- Non-rooted device

  ```
  USER     PID   PPID  NAME
  shell    166   1     /sbin/adbd
  ...
  shell    15721 166   /system/bin/sh
  ```
- Emulator

  ```
  USER     PID   PPID  NAME
  root     1183  1     /sbin/adbd
  ...
  root     2884  1183  /system/bin/sh
  ```

`sh` process, so is its parent process `adbd`, is owned by `root` on an emulator, in contrast to the `shell` owner on a non-rooted device. And a `root` user has a "permission" to access your app's sandbox, despite the [`android:exported`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) attribute set to `false`.