# Android TV trigger Recommendation service from adb

Tags: android, android-tv

I have the following service definition in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <service
        android:name=".service.recommendation.Service"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"/>
```

And the service declaration is as follows:

```
class Service : IntentService("RecommendationService"), ServiceContract.Service {
....
}
```

Is the recommendation service for an Android TV application.

I've tried to run this service via adb with `/adb shell am startservice com.epix.epix/.service.recommendation.Service` or even `/adb shell am startservice com.epix.epix/RecommendationService` with no luck. Had the same results by setting `export=true`, the service did not start.

Right now android chooses when to trigger my service, can I trigger this service from adb?

Comment: Explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37083375/3290339)

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Rooted devices can run services with export false, that is what i understand, but I am not able to run the service at all.

Comment: Then it's not clear what _"some goes for setting export=true"_ means... The way you use adb command might be wrong. Do you run those commands being `shell`-ed in?

Comment: I've edited the question, hope it makes more sens now. I simply try to run the service as I stated in the questio `/adb shell am startservice __name_of_the_service__`