# "adbd cannot run as root in production builds" even though the 'debug' build variant is selected?

Tags: android, gradle, android-emulator, adb, root

I'm trying to point an Android emulator to a local VM, for which I need to `adb root`. However, I'm getting this error:

```
$ adb root
adbd cannot run as root in production builds
```

Yet the build variant I am running of the `p2p-app` is `debug`:

[image]

The `build.gradle` for the `p2p-app` module includes the following:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            debuggable true
            versionNameSuffix '-' + gitBranchName()
            applicationIdSuffix '.fifa'
            ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotesFilePath = "fabric-changelog.txt"
            ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases = "android-engineers"

        }
    }
}
```

Since the `debug` variant has `debuggable true`, I would expect it to be possible to get root access to the emulator?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41607607/1778421

Comment: That error message is unclear. It really means "adbd cannot run as root in _production builds of the Android emulator_".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `adb root` *shell* command has nothing to do with any app's build variant. The command just tries to restart `adbd` (`d` stands for daemon) on a target device with root permissions. And it is a matter of the device (emulator) images build configuration to grant those.

In case of *Android* emulator configuration the root permissions cannot be granted. Moreover, it is totally redundant as both `adbd` and emulator's `shell` have elevated privileges compared to stock devices (*a.k.a non-root*).

<sup>In addition a very small extra explanation on differences between stock devices and emulators can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37083375/3290339).</sup>

Answer (score 18):

Following [ADB root is not working on emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923996/adb-root-is-not-working-on-emulator/45668555#45668555), I managed to overcome this limitation by creating an emulator from a **Google APIs** system image, not a **Google Play** one (see screenshot below).

[image]

With this emulator I was able to `adb root`:

```
$ adb root
restarting adbd as root
```